# clearing cache to get the values from Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

My web site has a shopping cart. when the person is ready to pay, I redirect my web page to  another credit card company web site that takes care of the credit card payment. Once the Credit card payment is done and user clicks on the finish button, I get data from that credit card company like which payment method was used and how much amount was charged. below is the code to get all the values:

```
  NameValueCollection nvc = Request.Form;
```

I get all the value when I clear my browser cache otherwise, I get the empty value in nvc. How can I write this code so that I dont need to clear the browser cache every time to get the values from Request.Form. I am using method="post" in my form tag to get all the values from the credit card company.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Request.From` is not in cache, it is the collection of values sent in a POST request

Comment: Use F12 developer tools to determine if the form is actually being posted to your page. Also, check if your page is being served from cache.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what payment method do you use.

I used to develop payment integration, and this is what i did:

1. submit POST request to credit card company
2. Credit card company will post back the result to my designated "processing.aspx".
3. The processing aspx is to get all the data from the parameters, or from the Form, just like you did. I create a record with new transaction id, and the credit-card-trx-id for matching purpose, along with some other info provided by credit card company.
4. After processing is done, I will then redirect to "completion.aspx" without bringing over the whole bunch of data, except the my-transaction-id.

The processing.aspx job is just to receive the input from credit card company ONLY.
It does not display the result, nor do any other thing.

If I want to display nicely, redirect it to another page such as completion.aspx, which it's job solely to display friendly message.

It is also good to separate the processing.aspx and completion.aspx. One of advantage is that you can do unit-testing by simulating the credit-card response manually to your processing.aspx.

In my project, the credit card company can actually allow to have different end-point for different status.

1. Processing.aspx ==> triggered by credit card when it is sucessul
2. ProcessingFailure.aspx ==> triggered by credit card when something wrong
3. ProcessingCancel.aspx ==> triggered by credit card when user cancel the payment.